# Chinese phrases akin to “back to the grindstone”?

Tags: phrase-request

A colorful way to mention you’re going back to work, especially after a break is by saying:

> back to the grindstone

This is just usually plainly, and rather matter of factly, translated as:

> 回去干活

Are there any phrases more figurative that are similar to “back to the grindstone”?

——

I’m not looking for any makeshift combination of words but something like 回去推磨 would be pretty fun as it calls 有钱能使鬼推磨 to mind.

Comment: I guess the slang word 搬砖 is what you want

Comment: @JasonSwift you can make it an answer.

Comment: “醒工砖”, as short for “醒醒，工头喊你搬砖了”

Comment: @user3332315 add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One analog I can think of is

> 回去搬砖了

This is a funny way of describing your job as less paid while you still have to work very hard on that.

Comment: why did you delete this?

Comment: Because I just saw Jason Swift had that in the comment.

Comment: that’s okay, answers should be answers not comments.